# How to get the data in a file dynamically using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, listview, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I'm trying to get the data which display in the content part of a page.In the home page I'm loading an xml file using `ajax()` and it displays the data in a listview. When we click on the item in the listivew it opens that related file in a separate page which is dynamically created.So every item contain separate files(which is in .txt files).In that dynamic page (`[data-role="content"]`) I'm loading a file which contains that item related data.I want to get the file data.

Creating dynamic page for displaying data in a file:

```
$($.mobile.pageContainer).append('<div data-role="page" id="' + seq + '" class="items">
  <div data-role="content" id="desc"></div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="my-footer">
  <div class="ui-block-a ui-bar-a" data-theme="a">
  <div align="left" style="padding-left:5px;padding-top:3px;height:33px;height:40px;">
  <a href="#home" class="ui-btn-left" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
  </div></div>
  <div class="ui-block-b ui-bar-a"><div align="center" style="padding-top:3px;height:33px;text-align:center;height:40px;">
  <div style="padding-bottom:7px;"><a href="" data-role="button" class="addToFavoritesDiv">Bookmark</a>
  <a href="" data-role="button" class="shareDiv">Share</a></div></div></div><div class="ui-block-c ui-bar-a">
  <div align="right" style="padding-top:3px;height:33px;height:40px;">
  <a href="#" class="ui-btn-right" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" data-iconpos="notext"></a></div></div></div></div>');

$('[data-role=page]#' + seq + ' [data-role=content]').load(file);
```

Actually I'm using `localStorage` to store the data.Data is storing in the form of listview everything is fine but I tried like getting the url of a page.when I click on the stored data item it opens that file. But the problem is I implement `swipe` effect for the `next` and `previous` page(items in the listview).

```
var url = $(location).attr('href');
var demo = localStorage.getItem(url);
// var s = '<li data-role=\"list-divider\"></li>';
$("#favoritesList").append('<li id="add"><a href="' + url + '" style="text-decoration:none;color:black">' + demo  + '</a></li>').attr('url', url);
```

So i think when I'm getting that url in the `localStorage` if we swipe up and down it loads the other files also. Is there any idea to get the only selected data in a file.

Thanks in Advance.